# Python class - Set & Delete methods?

Tags: python, class

First I'd like to mention that I am completely new to Python and I've found it a bit difficult to transition from C++. I apologize if my question comes off as elementary.

I have a class for 'songs' which I have initialized as following. It takes in data from a file that contains a song's ID, name, genre etc. all separated by `::`.

```
    def __init__(self):
            self.song_names = dict()
            self.song_genres = dict()

    def load_songs(self,  song_id):
            f = open(song_id)
            for line in f:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    component = line.split("::")
                    sid = components[0]
                    same= components[1]
                    sgenre=components[2]
            self.song_names[mid] = sname
            self.song_genres[mid] = sgenre
            f.close()
```

The program also takes in data from a file with 'users' information, separated as
`UserID::Gender::Age::Occupation::Zip` etc. and a file with 'ratings'.

I would I implement a function like **def set_song(sid, list((title,genres)))**
and something like **delete_song(sid)** ?

I'm going to have to wind up doing a ton more other functions, but if someone could help me with those two - at least to have a better idea of structure and syntax - handling the others should be easier.

Comment: It's hard to say how you would implement those when you don't say what you want them to do.  Are you saying you want calling `set_user` to change the contents of the users file?  How is this related to the song code you pasted?

Comment: tip: Python has unpacking, you can write `sid, name, genre = components[:3]`

Comment: Since I am taking data from those files and loading them onto a dictionary (hence in the __init__), I would like to set them in the dictionary through that method.

Comment: Rather than having several dictionaries mapping from ID to some property, consider creating a class to represent each row and then having a single dictionary mapping from an ID to a corresponding row object.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm mostly interested in seeing how I can implement a simple set & delete method using what I have instantiated - in order to be able to understand how it works, syntax wise etc. so I can understand the logic and apply it to future methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just inherit from dict and use its interface? That way you can use Python's standard mapping operations instead of rolling your own:

```
class Songs(dict):

    def load(self, song_id):
        with open(song_id, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                sid, name, genre = line.rstrip().split('::')[:3]
                self[sid] = [name, genre]

mysongs = Songs()
mysongs.load('barnes_and_barnes__fish_heads')
mysongs['barnes_and_barnes__fish_heads'] = ['roly poly', 'strange']  # set
del mysongs['barnes_and_barnes__fish_heads']                         # delete
```