# Implementing 'delete' method syntax (and set)

Tags: python, class, set

I'm writing my first Python class and I was wondering if this was correct syntax to remove a particular 'song' from my dictionary.
I load data from a file onto a dictionary and store it.

Is this syntax correct?

```
def delete_song(id): #Do I need to do self_song(self, id) instead?
            del self.song_names[id]
```

id is the song's ID, which is being passed. Does this delete a song from my dictionary? Earlier on in the code I had saved a song's name to self.song_names[id]= sname, which was from a component sname=components[1] from reading in the file.

---

Also, I'm having trouble understanding how to go about the set function. Is this start on the right track?

```
def set_song(id, list((title,genres))):
   self.movie_names[id] = title
   self.movie_genres[id] = genres
```

I figured out how to implement the get method and in it I use

**self.song_names[id] = sname** and
**self.song_genres[id] = sgenre**

Any tips?

Comment: If you're calling the function from the class, the function will generally need to take in self.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python class - Set & Delete methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818037/python-class-set-delete-methods)

Comment: I don't see where you set "mid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a chapter on classes [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html).

And, for deleting an entry from a dictionary, it is safer to use `pop`:

`self.song_names.pop(id, None)` <--- will not raise an error if `id` is not found

`del self.song_names[id]` <--- raises `KeyError` if `id` not found